# Binding text in ComboBox vertical instead of Horizontal

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to troubleshoot my ComboBox.  It's declared like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SampleComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedSample.SampleName}" />
```

SelectedSample returns a custom object, that has a property of SampleName that is a string type.  When I check the value while in debug mode, I see the correct text, "Sample 1".  But when it appears in the ComboBox, it looks like this:

```
S
a
m
p
l
e

1
```

Not sure why it does that because when I create a normal List someProperty, and bind to that property, the data shows up normal.

```
TestData 1
TestData 2
TestData 3
...
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Path=SelectedSample.SampleName
```

is treated as IEnumerable and you get an array of characters

Its an ItemSource property so you need to provide `IEnumerable<Something>` there

Answer (score 0):

The ItemsSource is being set to a string so it is treating it like a char array and putting it in one char at a time. You need to set the itemsource to a list property.